# MNIST Dataset - .gz files do not contain "raw" bytes

Tags: compression, database, gzip

I am trying to use the [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). However, when I download the .gz image file and then unzip it, I get a lot of "compressed" bytes. Here's a bit of it:

```
'Tπüó<$ﬁ˛˛˛˛Ò∆∆∆∆∆∆∆∆™4CrHr£„˛·˛˛˛˙Â˛˛åBCCC;Ï˛jS˝—ÈˇSÅ˛Ó,;˘˛>Ö˛ª   
Õ¯:~˛∂K˚9›˛¶À˛€#&˛˛M‡˛sÖ˛˛4=Ú˛˛4y˛˛€(y˛œt}´ˇˇñ]©˝˝˝˝˝˝⁄©˝˝˝’é∞˝˝z4˙˝“ 
Œ˝åM˚“z¯˝A—˝˝Au˜˝∆
L˜˝Á?Ä˝˝ê∞ˆ˝üÍ˝È#∆˝˝çN¯˝Ω»˝˝çÜ˝˝≠
```

I think these are "compressed" bytes, at least. However, as per the "file format explainer" on the bottom of the page, the content of the file should be some 32-bit integers and then a bunch of unsigned bytes. Obviously, this isn't what I'm seeing.
What is causing this to happen? Is it because I double-clicked the .gz file? Is it because I didn't decompress the file correctly? Is it due to a lack of technical knowledge, and this is how the files are supposed to be?
Basically what I said above was how do you fix the problem and how do you solve it.
By the way: I'm on a Mac OS 10.13.3. The file was downloaded from Google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the content of the file should be some 32-bit integers and then a bunch of unsigned bytes. Obviously, this isn't what I'm seeing.

No, that's exactly what you're seeing.

**All** files consist of raw bytes; everything else is a matter of interpretation, and depends on what program you're opening the file with.

If you open the file in a text editor, it will try to show text. It will never show raw byte values, but only the corresponding characters from the ASCII table (or from Unicode or another codepage).

However, the MNIST download page *does not* say that your data will be written down as decimal numbers in ASCII. Instead it directly uses byte values to encode data: a "32-bit integer" is spread across four bytes (8 bits each); an "unsigned byte" is, well, one byte.

In short, the downloaded file is in a custom format that requires special software to interpret it; a text editor won't do. Instead:

- You could open the file in a ["hex editor"](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) program. Hex editors *do* show raw byte values (they are meant specifically for editing binary files), although it's still up to you to make any sense of the data that's shown.
- You could write a short program to convert the data to a textual format. The original format MNIST describes is simple enough that it'd be some 5–10 lines of Python, for example.
- The files contain graphical data – raw bitmaps, as a series of pixels. So with some more programming they could be converted to a series of image files (BMP, GIF or PNG).

Comment: Oh. I don't know anything about data so... :P